# Google Search Console search analytics showing only a fraction of the traffic reported by Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

My Google Analtyics shows an steady audience of approx 180 visitors a day , most of them coming from organic search. However, Search Console queries show less than 40 clicks a month, which clearly doesn't match the data shown by Analytics.

About three months ago my site used to show more than 4000 clicks a month in Search Console queries, now it shows less than 40 and the audience has not changed, any idea on how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have all four versions of your property added to Google Search Console (`http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com`, and `https://www.example.com`)?   This is usually because you are not tracking the version that is actually getting the clicks.

Answer (score 1):

While Search Console and Analytics will never match perfectly, generally, these should be much closer. What changes did you make to your site three months ago? Stephen's comment about the different versions of your URL could help to explain the problem. In Search Console, there is a difference between https and http, www and non-www. So, if you had changed something on your domain to require https or to force www, perhaps Google Search Console is no longer tracking the correct version of your domain. You can read more information about this, and a few other possible explanations, [here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/08/05/google-search-console-clicks-vs-google-analytics-sessions/).

Comment: Maybe some of your organic traffic comes from Bing or other search engines?